# Z-index not working IE

Tags: html, css, z-index

New to Z-index, 
Have been trying different things to get the header and feature to show up at the top and bottom of the image,

This is the section of HTML

```
<div id="hero">

        <div id="header">
    <div id="headercontent">
        <div id="logo">
            The Bucks Arms
        </div><!-- #logo -->
        <div id="nav">
        <a href="index.php">Home</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="food.php">Food &amp; Drink</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="accommodation.php">Accommodation</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="about.php">About</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
        </div><!-- #nav -->
    </div><!-- #headercontent -->
</div><!-- #header -->
        <img id="heroimage" src="images/bucksoutside.jpg" alt="The outside of the beautiful old pub" /> 
        <div id="feature">
            <div id="featuretitlecontainer">
                <div id="featuretitle">
                </div><!-- #featuretitle -->
            </div><!-- #featuretitlecontainer -->
            <div id="featurecontainer"> 
                <div id="featuretext">
                </div><!-- #featuretext -->
            </div><!-- #featurecontainer -->
        </div><!-- #feature -->
    </div><!-- #hero -->
```

And this is the CSS

```
/* header */

#header {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#000;
    -khtml-opacity:.70; 
 -moz-opacity:.70; 
 -ms-filter:"alpha(opacity=70)";
  filter:alpha(opacity=70);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0.7);
  opacity:.70;
  position:relative;
  z-index:3;

}

#headercontent {

    width:960px;
    height:60px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#logo {
    padding:25px 0 0 0;
    font-size:30px;
    width:320px;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFF;
}

/* nav */

#nav {
    padding:38px 0 0 0;
    width:630px;
    float:right;
    margin:0px 0 0 0;
    text-align:right;
    color:#666;
}

/* hero */
#hero {
    width:100%;
    max-width:1400px;
    margin:0 auto;
    clear:both;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;

}

#heroimage {
    position: relative;
    top:-60px;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
    z-index:1;
}

/* Feature */
#feature {
    position:relative;
    top:-213px;
    margin:0 auto;
    z-index:2;
}

#featuretitle {
    -khtml-opacity:.70; 
 -moz-opacity:.70; 
 -ms-filter:"alpha(opacity=70)";
  filter:alpha(opacity=70);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0.7);
  opacity:.70; 
    font-size:25px;
    padding:5px 10px 5px 10px; 
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#000;
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    width:300px;
    margin:0 0 0 660px;
}

#featuretitlecontainer {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;  
}

#featurecontainer
{
position:relative;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#000;
    -khtml-opacity:.70; 
 -moz-opacity:.70; 
 -ms-filter:"alpha(opacity=70)";
  filter:alpha(opacity=70);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0.7);
  opacity:.70; 
}

#featuretext {
    padding:20px;
    margin:auto;
    width:960px;
    font-size:17px;
    color:#FFF;
    line-height:25px;
    background-color:#000;  
}
```

the site can be found at http://samdesigns.co.uk/bucksold
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm looking in IE and looks well

Comment: @Aguardientico Ok how interesting, so you can see the nav and the bit about new management?

Comment: IE10? 9? 8?  Just curious.

Comment: @BjornJohnson IE9 is what I am using

Comment: What's it supposed to look like?  It looks fine in IE9, but "fine" doesn't mean it looks like you would like it to look.

Comment: @BjornJohnson It should have a navigation at the top of the image and a section at the bottom of the image which have a 70% opacity background. Best thing to do is look at it in Chrome to see what its meant to be like.

Comment: In compatible mode it looks good in IE9

Comment: @Gangadhar are you able to see the nav at the top of the page? maybe it is just my machine

Comment: @Sam Meyer yes i am able to see both nav at top and "under new management" section at bottom over the image

Comment: @Gangadhar Ok thats awesome! Maybe it is just my machine! Will try and get hold of a couple more PC's in the morning (3am here) and investigate further. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Sam Meyer  you can set the comapatible view in the browser setting, try to set it and check in your machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is easily fixed and not actually related to z-index. You have used the alpha opacity filter incorrectly.

The value should not be `0.7`.

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0.7)
```

It should be `70`.

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=70)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the

z-index: 3 !important;

Comment: Just added that and no success

Answer (score 0):

I would personally reorder the HTML so I didn't have to worry about z-index (especially if coupled with the next part of my answer).

```
<div id="hero">
<img id="heroimage" />
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="feature"></div>
</div>
```

I would also absolutely position the header and feature divs to be at the top and bottom of #hero, respectively.

```
/*example css:*/
#header {
   top:0
}
#feature {
   bottom:0
}
```

Without more analysis or info, I'm not sure why you went with the relative positioning or why you wanted to clip the hero image with the negative top positioning.  Maybe you have a great reason for those things.